# Serialize/Deserialize different property names?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have an old system which in a request info call returns xml with names that look like:

postalCodeField, firstNameField...

That same system then has a modify call which takes xml that looks like:

PostalCode, fistName, lastName....

Is there a way to build an object that would deserialize the request, yet serialize the xml output with different names?

Specifically:

```
public class RequestInfo
{
    public string firstNameField{get;set;}
    public string lastNameField{get;set;}
}

public class ModifyInfo
{
    public string firstName{get;set;}
    public string lastName{get;set;}
    public ModifyInfo(){}
    public ModifyInfo(RequestInfo ri)
    {
        firstName = ri.firstNameField
        .....
    }
}
```

Is there a way through say attributes to make these into the same object?

**EDIT**

Is there a way to have a single object that would accept one tag name on deserialize, then output a different name on serialize?

< myTagField /> (deserialize to) myObj.MyTag (serialize to) < MyTag />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to note which actual serializer you're using.  Every different serializer works differently.

I assume you're using the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`.  If that is the case, then you want to use the attributes in the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace such as XmlElementAttribute like so:

```
public class Person
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "firstNameField")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

This assumes the field is an XML element.  If it's an attribute, use the `XmlAttribute` attribute.

Comment: Yes I am using that serializer and I am familiar with the attribute, however, while the attribute allows me to deserialize a tag into a property with a different name, it also serializes that property to the attribute listed name. So having that attribute alone wont fix my issue.

Comment: You can add that attribute at run time, during deserialization only, using XmlAttributeOverrides.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx) on MSDN. You will need XmlElement for properties and, possibly, XmlRoot for root class.

If you need to override property names only during deserialization, than you can define attributes dynamically, using XmlAttributeOverrides:

```
public XmlSerializer CreateOverrider()
{
    XmlElementAttribute xElement = new XmlElementAttribute();
    xElement.ElementName = "firstName"; 

    XmlAttributes xElements = new XmlAttributes();
    xElements.XmlElements.Add(xElement);

    XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    xOver.Add(typeof(RequestInfo), "firstNameField", xElements);

    XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RequestInfo), xOver);
    return xSer;
}
```